# I added 10 buttons using me.controls.Add(mybutton). how can I give each button an XML file to write its property?

Tags: vb.net

I added 10 dynamical buttons by using `Me.Controls.Add(mybutton)`, I want to create a data.xml to write the size and loction of button fo every button ,such as :

```
button1     data1.xml
button2     data2.xml
button3     data3.xml
...         ...
button10     data10.xml
```

I use `Dim` file As New `IO.StreamWriter("datai.xml")`, but all button property values are written to an XML file.
my code is :

```
Dim file As New IO.StreamWriter("datai.xml")
file.WriteLine("width=" & sender.width)
file.WriteLine("height=" & sender.height)
file.WriteLine("x=" & sender.left)
file.WriteLine("y=" & sender.top)
file.Close()
```

how to solve this bug?

Comment: For a start, that code is not writing XML.  Just because you give the file a ".xml" extension, that doesn't mean that it's an XML file.  If you fill a jar with salt and then slap a label that says "Sugar" on it, does the contents of the jar magically become sugar?

Comment: If you want to write out those properties of the `Buttons` then loop through the `Buttons` and write those properties.  You can either loop through the `Controls` collection you added them to and filter in whatever way is appropriate, e.g. use the same prefix in the `Name` for each one, or else you can add them to another separate collection as well and loop through that.

Comment: Oh, but that's not the main problem.The main question is how to make each button correspond to a file that writes its property?

Comment: Are you saying that you want separate files for each `Button`?  Why would you do that when you can write one file for all of them?  If that's not what you're saying then I have already answered your question: use a loop.

Comment: *"Oh, but that's not the main problem"*. But it is a problem. I can read. I can see what you're asking. I'm just pointing out an glaring issue with your code that you seem not to have considered?  Should we just ignore such things?

Comment: I know your mean. I just want to express that I want to know how to make each button correspond to a file that writes its property. As to xml file, I can change it to txt , It doesn't really matter.

Comment: I don't know why you would want to use separate files but the solution is still virtually identical.  You still loop through the `Buttons` and you still write the output in the same way. You would just open and close a file inside the loop instead of outside.  Presumably you would use the `Name` of the `Button` as the file name but that's up to you.

Comment: because my tutor asked me to write a compiler .One of his requeires is my program could add and remove buttons, and output the values of the location and size of the dynamically added buttons into a data file

Comment: Your tutor asked you to write a compiler and you don't know how to write a loop? I suggest you to change school

Comment: *"output the values […] into a data file"*. If it is **A** data file then that's not a separate file for each `Button`. I don't know if there's a language problem here but you are not being very clear at all and it doesn't necessarily seem that you even have a clear idea yourself.